# Is that possible to execute newman collections from jasmine tests

Tags: node.js, jasmine, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have written a few api tests using jasmine in node platform. and we have some of the existing api testcases in postman collections. Now we are thinking of executing both the test cases in single execution..

We were able to execute the postman collections through newman commandline tool...

So is that possible to execute the newman collections from node platform / from jasmine test cases...

Someone please give me some idea on it.. We are badly in need of the combined execution....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: *We are badly in need of the combined execution....* - why? Looks like XY problem. Even if being possible, wrapping it with Jasmine just provides additional moving parts and impairs efficiency and stability. Usually you don't need test runner for test runner for test runner for test runner...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Newman test directly for jasmine, the json structure of the files focused for Newman runner.

If you want to use scripts directly from postman - use newman for each test case
If NOT, use Mocha & Chai for comprehensive API automated testing
https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai